# Showing a masked BTProgressHUD without blocking the tab bar?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uitabbarcontroller, svprogresshud

Is it possible to show a BTProgressHUD with a mask without preventing interaction with the tab bar? In other words, can the mask on a BTProgressHUD be constrained to just the tab's currently shown view controller instead of the full window?

```
BTProgressHUD.Show(status: "Oh hai", maskType: ProgressHUD.MaskType.Gradient);
```

[image: BTProgressHUD mask blocks the ability to switch tabs.]

I am trying to swap out MTMBProgressHUD for BTProgressHUD (because [reasons](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26760)). Unfortunately, when I show a BTProgressHUD with a mask, it will block the user from selecting another tab while it is shown (something MTMBProgressHUD didn't prevent). I definitely need to block any progression/interaction within the current tab's view controller, but I don't mind if the user switches to another tab instead of waiting for the current tab to complete whatever task is requiring the progress HUD.

Here is the [full sample code Gist](https://gist.github.com/patridge/d08bcb4923e14c432305). It is a bit more complex since it includes the tab bar controller and each tab needs to be able to control their own individual HUDs (when this issue is resolved).

Comment: Didn't work with BTProgressHUD for a while, but as far as I can remember it lives out of the box fullscreen on the main window. But as the code is available on GitHub you could easily change that. Quick check at https://github.com/nicwise/BTProgressHUD/blob/master/BTProgressHUD/ProgressHUD.cs: lines 240 & 241 look interesting.

Comment: That was what the BTProgressHUD creator was suggesting on Twitter as well. Thanks for the line numbers, though. I hadn't made it that far yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [some discussion on Twitter](https://twitter.com/fastchicken/status/563387771734089728) with the creator of BTProgressHUD, it was determined this isn't possible in the current v1.15 release. He suggesting modifying the source to make this happen. I was able to put together the a [working version in just a few lines](https://github.com/patridge/BTProgressHUD/commit/abcac38f5df4911018737865b5deca963ad7ee8f). (It would still need work to integrate with the `BTProgressHUD.Show` methods that use a shared instance, but I need discrete HUDs per tabs.)

If you build from this fork, you can then create a BTProgressHUD with a parent view (vs. defaulting to the window) which will restrict the coverage of the overlay mask.

```
var progressHud = new ProgressHUD(View); // ctor overload requires the forked version
progressHud.Show(status: labelText, maskType: ProgressHUD.MaskType.Gradient);
```

[image: Animated GIF showing tab switching while a HUD is shown]